# Problem installing Google Chrome to Phone

Tags: app-brain, google-chrome-to-phone

I installed [Google Chrome to Phone](http://code.google.com/p/chrometophone/) via AppBrain. AppBrain displays the app as installed (both the website, and my AppBrain app). When I click 'open', I get "This app is not executable".
When I click 'uninstall', I get 'The application was not found in the list of installed applications.'

I indeed do not see it in the list. What should I do to install it? (BTW, I also can't find it on the Google Market)

Answer (score 6):

> (BTW, I also can't find it on the
>   Google Market)

If you cannot find an application in the Market, this means the application is not compatible with your device. AppBrain cannot install applications that you cannot find from the Market, since in the AppBrain installation, you are brought to the Market to install your application (AppBrain is application discovery service, not alternative Market).

Are you possibly using Android 2.1, which does not have the Cloud-to-Device Messaging API, and therefore cannot use Chrome to Phone? Or possibly you have multiple phones linked to your AppBrain account?

Comment: I'm using Nexus One with Froyo (2.2), it should work. Only a single phone is linked to my AppBrain account.

Comment: @ripper234 It may be because you're from Israel? They might have released it to only specific countries.

Comment: Possibly, this has happened before. Is a direct installation link?

Comment: @ripper234 see my answer for a possible workaround.  I don't see a download apk link, but the app appears to be open source

Answer (score 1):

It may be because you live in Israel.

Try using [Market Enabler](https://market.android.com/details?id=ch.racic.android.marketenabler&feature=search_result) to circumvent that problem and see if it'll show in the market for you then.

Comment: Or more so that he *lives in* Israel. The market isn't discriminatory is it? ;)

Comment: For some reason the Market Enabler never worked for me.

Comment: @gary haha, fixed my grammar :)  @ripper234 hmm, I've personally never used it but everyone recommends it for non-US country downloading app problems